# Not showing coredata framework in linked frameworks and libraries in Xcode 6.3

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I am trying to add CoreData.Framework to my application but it is not showing in in linked frameworks and libraries.
please some one help me to get coreDta back to my Xcode 6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 6 uses **modules**, so Apple frameworks do not need to be explicitly linked. **You can just import the framework to use it.**

Modules are much better than old frameworks where an import statement copies the entire header over.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just include the line `import CoreData` at the top of your class and it will allow you access. No need for frameworks to be linked.